# Permission error when trying to delete shapefiles with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, windows, delete

The task is to merge many layers in a folder (temp_layer) and check for valid geometry for further processing. The folder where are the layer data are is external and should be copied local for processing purposes. A specific field `"field_1"` is extracted from the layer data.

A solution was found but I don't understand it. If the iterator is `layer.getFeatures()` I cannot delete the files after processing (code below), but if the iterator is feats the files are deleted without an error (replace `layer.getFeatures()` with feats).

```py
import os
from shutil import copyfile

list_of_filepaths = []
path = os.getenv('USERPROFILE') + "\\downloads\\temp_layer\\"
path_local = os.getenv('APPDATA') +"\\"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        copyfile(path+name,path_local+name)
        list_of_filepaths.append(path_local+name)

k=0
ifeat = []

lyr = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:25832", "result", "memory")
lyr_p = lyr.dataProvider()

try:
    for filename in list_of_filepaths:
        if ".shp" in filename:
            k=k+1
            layer = QgsVectorLayer(filename,"templayer","ogr")
            if k==1:
                attr = layer.dataProvider().fields().toList()
                attr = [f for f in attr if "field_1" in str(f)]
                lyr_p.addAttributes(attr)
                lyr.updateFields()
            
            feats = layer.getFeatures()
            for f in layer.getFeatures():
                geom = f.geometry()
                if geom.validateGeometry() == []:
                    ff = QgsFeature()
                    ff.setFields(lyr_p.fields())
                    ff.setGeometry(geom)
                    ff['field_1'] = f['field_1']
                    ifeat.append(ff)
                    del(geom)
                    del(f)
            del(layer)
    lyr_p.addFeatures(ifeat)

    pathtowrite = os.path.dirname(iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri())
    print("Writing to Path of active Layer: " + str(pathtowrite))

    options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
    options.actioanOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer
    options.EditionCapability = QgsVectorFileWriter.CanAddNewLayer
    options.driverName="SQLite"
    options.layerName = lyr.name()
    writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, pathtowrite + "\merged.sqlite", options)

    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(pathtowrite + "\merged.sqlite","merged","ogr")
    lyr.dataProvider().setEncoding(u'UTF-8')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)

    for name in files:
        os.remove(path_local+name)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```